# Laravel 5.0 listen email send event and change recipients

Tags: php, laravel, email, events

I just want to catch all email sending and change the to attribute when run in debug mode.

I have a working Laravel 4 code (events.php):

```
Event::listen('emails.*', function($param)
{
    Mail::send(Event::firing(), array('param'=>$param), function($message) use ($param){

        if ( Config::get('mail.mail_only_for_developer') )
            $message->to('debug@debug.com');
        else
            $message->to( $param['to_email'] );

        $message->from( $param['from'] );
        $message->subject( $param['subject'] );
    });
});
```

How can I achieve this in laravel 5.0 and 5.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple options (logging, Mailtrap, etc.) but I think the `Universal To` option is the best approach for your requirements. See [mail options in local dev](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail#mail-and-local-development) documentation.

In your `config/mail.php` set the `to` variable:

```
'to' => [
    'address' => 'dev@domain.com',
    'name' => 'Dev Example'
],
```

Comment: I did not notice the documentation.
That's exactly what I need.